# Is there a way to clear the terminal/console in Nitrious.io

Tags: nitrousio

In the Mac terminal simply hitting command K will clear the terminal window.  Is there a way to do this with the Nitrious.io console window?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the *clear* command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcut **Ctrl-L** instead, which is universal for Linux terminals.